# Как сделать background на всю ширину headera, если есть общий div wrapper с ограничением по ширине в 90 rem?

Tags: html, css, background

Задача сделать белый фон (background) на всю ширину для headera и footera. Но есть общий div wrapper с ограничением по ширине в 90 rem для всего контента.
Подскажите как растянуть белый фон на всю ширину для headera и footera только?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Maven+Pro:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a,
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  /* background-color: #f8f2f2; */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #A1C4FD 0%, #C2E9FB 50%);
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #a1c4fd 0%, #c2e9fb 100%); */
  /* background: linear-gradient(to right, #B2FEFA, #0ED2F7); */
  /* background: linear-gradient(to right, #accbee 0%, #e7f0fd 50%); */
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #accbee 0%, #e7f0fd 100%); */
  /* background: linear-gradient(to right, #83a4d4, #b6fbff); */
  /* background-image: url("../image1.jpg"); */
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 90.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  padding: 2rem 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.header__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__link {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #0046FF;
}

.header__button {
  flex: 0 0 16rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-menu {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 1.9rem;
  height: 1.12rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.icon-menu::before,
.icon-menu::after {
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.icon-menu span {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.header__login {
  background-color: #0046FF;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.9rem;
  padding: 0.1rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.search__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.search__row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 2.5rem 0 2.5rem 0;
}

.search__row img:last-child {
  width: 40%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 426px) {
  .search__row {
    margin: 0 0 1.25rem;
  }
  .search__row img:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
  .search__row img:first-child {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

.search__bar {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.search__input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #80A7E0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.9rem;
  padding: 0.6rem 0.9rem;
}

.search__cards {
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.search__cards-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0 2.5rem 0;
}

.search__cards-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 426px) {
  .search__cards-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
}

.search__cards-button {
  background-color: #0044ff;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  line-height: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* font-weight: 700; */
}

.search__cards-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1.9rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1025px) {
  .search__cards-content {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    gap: 0.5rem;
  }
}

.search__cards-item {
  max-width: 14.3rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  background-color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1025px) {
  .search__cards-item {
    width: 31%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 769px) {
  .search__cards-item {
    width: 48%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 528px) {
  .search__cards-item {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.search__cards-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 13rem;
}

.search__cards-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.search__cards-description {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem 0.6rem;
}

.search__cards-subtitle {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.search__cards-link {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.scale {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scale img {
  transition: 1.5s;
  display: block;
}

.scale img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

footer {
  /* max-width: 1380px; */
  height: 12.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 4.3rem 0;
  /* border-radius:0.9rem; */
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  /* max-width: 98.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto; */
}

.footer__col {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 3rem 0 0 0;
}

.footer__col ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1.9rem;
}

.footer__col ul li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
  color: rgb(128, 127, 128);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer__col ul li a:hover {
  color: #0046FF;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
}

.footer__col a img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 0 40px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer__col a img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer__social-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}


/* .footer__col a img:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;

} */


/* .links a:last-child  {
    margin-right: 0;
    background-color: red;
} */


/* .links a:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 40px;
    background-color: red;

  } */


/* @media screen and (max-width: 1324px) {
        .container {
            max-width: 60.5rem;
            margin: 0 auto;
    }
} */

@media screen and (max-width: 1107px) {
  #sist2 {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 0.5rem;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <header class="header ">
    <div class="header__container container">
      <a class="header__link" href="#">LOGO</a>
      <div class="header__button">
        <a class="header__login" href="#">Log in</a>
        <a href="#menu" type="button" class="menu__icon icon-menu"><span></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="search__cards-content">
    <div class="search__cards-item">
      <div class="search__cards-img scale">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQv9Nc1vr_cBW_frNDe8gnNTuTBbLVwcxBdcFh-y3-dTJpzeOrLbxMEcegIaF9-5lr8BMk&usqp=CAU" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="search__cards-description">
        <a class="search__cards-subtitle" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="search__cards-link" href="#">View more →</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="search__cards-item">
      <div class="search__cards-img scale">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559297434-fae8a1916a79?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8dHJhbnNwb3J0fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="search__cards-description">
        <a class="search__cards-subtitle" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="search__cards-link" href="#">View more →</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="search__cards-item">
      <div class="search__cards-img scale">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446694292248-2c2a7e575b1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8dHJhbnNwb3J0fGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="search__cards-description">
        <a class="search__cards-subtitle" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="search__cards-link" href="#">View more →</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="search__cards-item">
      <div class="search__cards-img scale">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488998628026-a1a79746cdcd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTJ8fHRyYW5zcG9ydHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="search__cards-description">
        <a class="search__cards-subtitle" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="search__cards-link" href="#">View more →</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="search__cards-item">
      <div class="search__cards-img scale">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614976523626-d598aafd4fda?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fHRyYW5zcG9ydHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="search__cards-description">
        <a class="search__cards-subtitle" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="search__cards-link" href="#">View more →</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Second row -->
    <div class="search__cards-item">
      <div class="search__cards-img scale">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475088092121-b7d3cd6e1482?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTN8fHRyYW5zcG9ydHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="search__cards-description">
        <a class="search__cards-subtitle" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="search__cards-link" href="#">View more →</a>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="search__cards-item">
      <div class="search__cards-img scale">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1604778202015-3071e0d7f29b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTd8fHRyYW5zcG9ydHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="search__cards-description">
        <a class="search__cards-subtitle" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="search__cards-link" href="#">View more →</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="search__cards-item">
      <div class="search__cards-img scale">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1592963219838-6045ccbe0563?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTR8fHRyYW5zcG9ydHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="search__cards-description">
        <a class="search__cards-subtitle" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="search__cards-link" href="#">View more →</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="search__cards-item sist1">
      <div class="search__cards-img scale">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580981433573-c5804ced20ad?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8bW9kZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="search__cards-description">
        <a class="search__cards-subtitle" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="search__cards-link" href="#">View more →</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="search__cards-item sist2">
      <div class="search__cards-img scale">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1445264918150-66a2371142a2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjF8fHRyYW5zcG9ydHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="search__cards-description">
        <a class="search__cards-subtitle" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="search__cards-link" href="#">View more →</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="row container">
      <div class="footer__links footer__col">
        <ul class="footer_links-list">
          <li class="footer_links-items"><a href="#">Personal data policy</a></li>
          <li class="footer_links-items"><a href="#">Terms of use</a></li>
          <li class="footer_links-items"><a href="#">Rules</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="footer__links footer__col">
        <ul class="footer__links-list">
          <li class="footer_links-items"><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li class="footer_links-items"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
          <li class="footer_links-items"><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>


      <div class="footer__links footer__col">
        <div class="footer__social-links links">
          <a href=""><img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluency/344/pinterest.png" alt="I"></a>
          <a href=""><img src="https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/2x/instagram-new--v2.png" alt="T"></a>
          <a href=""><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/twitter.png" alt="D"></a>
          <a href=""><img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/2x/facebook.png" alt="F"></a>


        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: сделать header абсолютным? ну или fixed, что вам больше подходит. Либо переверстать

Comment: Спасибо за совет, попробую сделать абсолютным.

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов масса.

1. Сделать хедер и футер абсолютно позиционированными.
2. Добавить хедеру и футеру псевдоэлементы, которые подложить под содержимое и спозиционировать абсолютно.
3. Задать хедеру и футеру `box-shadow` без размытия и со сдвигом - вариант простой, но при очень больших размерах экрана тень может не достать до краев.
4. Самый правильный вариант: вынести хедер и футер из общего враппера и растянуть на всю ширину. А контенту в них задать собственные врапперы.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, подскажите, не совсем понял вариант номер 2 и вариант номер 3?